# Converting end user local to UTC and back

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Wondering if I'm doing this correctly or if I went too far or not far enough.
I have a scheduling/POS system which each location has it's own data.

Each location will report on it's own data.
The "owner" will be able to run reports for all locations.

I'm storing datetime as UTC.

Each location has it's timezone stored.

The end user passes over appointment information to the application which calls a stored proc. This grabs the locations stored timezone and converts local to UTC.

```
DECLARE @offeset VARCHAR(6)
SELECT @offeset = tz.current_utc_offset FROM sys.time_zone_info tz
INNER JOIN Location cl ON cl.TimeZoneStandardName = tz.[name]
WHERE cl.LocationID = @locationID

DECLARE @newStart DATETIME = dbo.fnConvertLocalToUTC(@startTimeLocal, @offset)
DECLARE @newEnd DATETIME = dbo.fnConvertLocalToUTC(@endTimeLocal, @offset)
```

Function: fnConvertLocalToUTC

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fnConvertLocalToUTC](
@datetime datetime2,
@offset varchar(6)
)
returns datetime2
as
BEGIN
return SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, CONVERT(varchar, @datetime, 121) + ' ' + @offset), 0)
END
```

Pulling a list of today's appointments I created a view that contains the following to convert UTC back to their local time.

```
SELECT ....
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), dbo.fnConvertUTC(a.StartTimeUTC, cl.TimeZoneStandardName), 120) AS StartTime
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), dbo.fnConvertUTC(a.EndTimeUTC, cl.TimeZoneStandardName), 120) AS EndTime
FROM Appointment a
INNER JOIN Location cl ON cl.LocationID = a.LocationID
WHERE 
    CAST(dbo.fnConvertUTC(a.StartTimeUTC, cl.TimeZoneStandardName) AS DATE) = CAST(dbo.fnConvertUTC(GETUTCDATE(), cl.TimeZoneStandardName) AS DATE)
```

Function: fnConvertUTC

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fnConvertUTC](
@datetime datetime2,
@timezonename varchar(60)
)
returns datetime2
as
BEGIN
return CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(@datetime, DATEPART(TZOFFSET, @datetime AT TIME ZONE @timezonename)))
END
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I'm I handling this correctly or did I over complicate the process?

Comment: Unfortunately SO is about answering specific questions, not offering opinions.

Comment: You might want to post this question on https://CodeReview.StackExchange.Com